Не удается отформатировать WD Blue SA500.1
товарищи. Для начала немного контекста по вопросу. Закупил на вторичке WD Blue SA500.1 (SATA SSD от бывшего SanDisk на 500ГБ). На месте проверил на ноуте продавца с помощью USB 3.0 через CrystalDiskInfo, выработка всего 2,7ТБ, 533 часа работы, серийник по сайту пробивается, показывает именно эту модель с этими спецификациями. На месте форматнул из NTFS в ExFAT, все тоже прошло без проблем. Погонял его для приличия еще в CrystalDiskMark пробниками 8ГБ, тоже все нормально, скорости (для случайных операций чтения/записи. Последовательные, конечно, проверить так нельзя) в пределах погрешности совпадают с табличными. Приехал домой, воткнул в компьютер через тот же USB 3.0 to SATA, чтобы сделать из него Windows 11 To Go. Открываю Rufus, выбираю образ винды, выбираю этот диск, начинаю установку. После создания карты разделов Rufus кидает мне ошибку в духе «Ошибка обращения к диску, сбой в работе I/O модуля», после чего начинается самый цирк.
Итак, по пунктам:

Windows: диск в проводнике винды не отображается, но в виндовой дисковой утилите его видно. Любые попытки взаимодействовать с ним оттуда намертво вешают эту самую утилиту.
macOS: диск даже монтируется, но только на чтение и с предупреждением, что исправить карту разделов система не может, поэтому надо все важное сохранять и стирать диск. При попытке стереть диск diskutil повисает на моменте создания карты разделов. Кстати, видна карта разделов на диске - это 16,8МБ служебный раздел винды, основной раздел на 500ГБ в ExFAT (причем с файлами-пробниками от CrystalDiskMark) и 1МБ неразмеченного пространства. Пробовал ковырять его также через Paragon Hard Disk Manager, но после первой попытки отформатировать диск программа легла и больше не встает.
Ubuntu: диск не монтируется, но определяется в lsblk и местной дисковой утилите. Диаграмма разделов аналогичная, за исключением того, что на месте 500ГБ раздела бубунта видит неразмеченное пространство. Эффект от попытки стирания диска/раздела аналогичен macOS, только ошибку кидает быстрее. Кроме того, при очередном переподключении диска к бубунте SMART начал орать, что диску пришел конец. При этом smartctl, как и CrystalDiskInfo, показывает, что ресурса по всем параметрам еще море. После этих выкриков SMART бубунта больше не дает вывести диск из режима сна.

Что было предпринято:

заменен шнур, которым SSD подкидывается к компу, на Type-C to SATA. Эффекта ноль.
заменен компьютер. Все операции производились на MacBook Pro 15 2016 и iMac 5K 2017. На MacBook не пробовал только Ubuntu за неимением на нем оной.
как уже описано выше, были предприняты попытки форматирования как диска, так и его разделов по-отдельности. Пробовал форматировать в FAT32, ExFAT, APFS, NTFS. Все это дело пробовал делать только с таблицей разделов GUID, но не думаю, что MBR здесь даст иной результат. Также пробовал удалять разметку вовсе. Все это, естественно, под всеми 3 системами (кроме проприетарных технологий).
под бубунтой выполнил sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=2 status=progress, где sdb - тот злополучный диск. Программа отчиталась об отправке и получении 2 пакетов суммарным весом 1МБ, но эффекта это не дало никакого.

Собственно, задача привести SSD в чувства. Ну или хотя бы объяснить, с какой аппаратной неисправностью я умудрился столкнуться на нулевом диске.
UPD: добавлен смарт для диска. 
UPD2: ругань смарта на плохое состояние оказалась вызвана Type-A to SATA переходником. Более того, режим работы - SATA I. При использовании Type-C to SATA смарт в порядке, работает SATA III, но проблемы все те же.

"SMART начал орать, что диску пришел конец" - вывод SMART можно было бы здесь привести для информативности. Ну а вообще не вижу причин не доверять такому выводу.

Вывод smartctl приведу (нужно ли что-то еще?), но я просто искренне не понимаю, на основании каких метрик он пришел к такому выводу, если абсолютно все выводимые по запросу демонстрируют прекрасную сохранность.

Компы староваты. Скорее всего не хватает питания на портах USB. Попробуй работает ли он в сата порту с блоком питания напрямую

Вроде для SSD много питания и не надо? Я не испытывал проблем с USB-SATA на компах самой разной старости

Надо дмесг смотреть

У меня были проблемы с переходником усб сайта, если его включить на один проводок вместо двух.

Шутка про старость смешная, но год был нужен для указания аппаратных возможностей машин. А по Thunderbolt 3 они на выход 15Вт выдают, от 5В до 12В и током от 1,2А до 3А. Рядом с ним работает Silicon Power SP60 на 256ГБ, ему при подключении по любому из кабелей питания хватает без проблем. Возможно, конечно, что WD более прожорливые. Но тогда я бы не форматнул его на ноуте продавца, в который закупаемый SSD втыкался по все рому же кабелю.

Попробуй ещё раз на чужом ноуте.

Пробовал на ноуте идентичном ноуту владельца. Результат тот же.
